# Rotating the bucket in circular motion without spilling water

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertia

In the bucket experiment when the bucket reaches the top of the circle why will it have a normal force acting on the water downwards? Doesn't normal force oppose any other force? There is no force acting upwards... (As we are an observer in an inertial frame so we wont consider the centrifugal force because it is a pseudo force)
[image]

Comment: In fact there is a reaction to the normal force and it is given by the contact force the liquid applies on the bucket. This happens even when the bucket is at the top of the trajectory, unless the water falls off.

Comment: And what would be the magnitude of this contact force?

Comment: Why are you removing the `homework` tag?

Comment: because it isn't my homework and the discussion is more about a concept than the solution of this question in particular

Comment: @OsheenSachdev: Have you really read the tag wiki? Homework doesn't have to mean literally a question of homework assignment; it can be any self-studied problem like the one here. To know more, click on [tag:homework].

Comment: Hi Osheen Sachdev. Welcome to Phys.SE. Echoing @MAFIA36790's above comments, if you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to focus on one thing, here. The nature of the normal force.

You write

> Doesn't normal force oppose any other force?

which is a easy impression to get when you are introduced to the normal force in the context of things sitting on other things in a gravitational field, but that's not the best way to think about it.

The normal force *keeps things from occupying the same space*.

So consider a book sitting on the lab bench. It's subject to gravity, and in the absence of other forces would fall. But to fall it would have to occupy the same space as the solid top of the bench. The normal force is the interaction between to two objects that resists their inter-penetrating. In this case it has to provide a force that is equal and opposite to that of gravity to make that happen.

In the case of the water in the bucket, it's inertia would take it in a straight line, gravity modifies that into a parabola, but the sides and bottom of the bucket are moving in a circle for both those things to be true (the bucket goes in a circle and the water goes in a parabola) the water would have to move through the bottom of the bucket. The normal force serves to prevent the water from penetrating the solid material of the bucket and must supply whatever forces (beyond that of gravity) are necessary to cause the motion to be in a circle.

Comment: But shouldn't normal force point sideways then...because water wants to go tangentially but the sides of the bucket prevent that?

Comment: The normal from the sides of the bucket points toward the inside of the bucket all the way around. The normal from the bottom of the bucket points (roughly) toward the center of the circle (my shoulder joint when I do this demo in class).  Remember that for circular motion $\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{v}}{\mathrm{d}t}$ points to the middle of the circle and that is the direction of the force that must be imposed on the water to keep it moving in a circle.

Comment: As there is normal force pushing water from the bottom of the bucket, there must be a force pushing the water towards the bucket. I don't understand when the tension is inwards and water wants to go tangentially due to inertia then what force is pushing it outwards? considering the observer to be in an inertial frame there is no centrifugal force too...

Comment: Remember that the water is *not* in equilibrium (because it is moving in a circle, which means that it is accelerating). The forces not only don't need to cancel out they need to *not* cancel out.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a scenario where the bucket is rotated at just the right speed so that the centripetal acceleration required to keep the water on a circular path is exactly 9.81 $ms^{-1}$. Then at the top of the rotation, all the centripetal acceleration is supplied by gravity.

However the bucket might be rotating faster in any given scenario but it still rotates on a fixed radius. Since the force required to maintain circular motion is given by

$F=\frac{mv^2}{r}$

the force needs to be greater at higher velocities if the radius is constant. This means that gravity is no longer able to supply all the acceleration required to keep the water inside the bucket on its circular path.

The water *wants* to move to a larger radius but it cannot because the bucket is in the way. Hence the water feels a reaction force from the bucket. This contact force is simply the force required to hold the water at a given radius minus the force of gravity:

$F_N=\frac{mv^2}{r}-F_g$

Another way to think about it is if you desperately tried to move through a wall the wall would exert a force on you and the force would increase the harder you tried.

Comment: I don't understand when the tension is inwards and water wants to go tangentially due to inertia then what force is pushing it outwards? considering the observer to be in an inertial frame there is no centrifugal force too...

Comment: You have to remember that the bucket is also following the circular path that the water takes

Comment: There isn't actually a force acting outwards, it is only perceived that way. As explained in dmckee's answer the normal force is just what is keeping the water from going through the bucket.

Comment: but why does the water want to go through the bucket from its bottom, doesn't it want to go tangentially

Comment: Yes but think about it. When the water moves tangentially, the bucket has also moved a bit so it is actually hitting the bottom of the bucket.

Comment: Let's assume the bottom of the bucket forms the circle in which water rotates. At every point in time the force exerted by water is tangential to the circle and hence perpendicular to the bottom of the bucket

Comment: By the time the bucket moves, water has also moved it's direction of force

Comment: Well that is the explanation. I'll try one more time with a different analogy. Its like you keep catching the water with the bucket by moving it such that it can never go off on its tangent. The whole thing is a constant game of "catch" between bucket and water.

Answer (score 2):

> In the bucket experiment when the bucket reaches the top of the circle why will it have a normal force acting on the water downwards?

The normal contact force is exerted by the bottom of the bucket as explicitly mentioned by the author. So, it is acting downward when the bucket is inverted.

> Doesn't normal force oppose any other force? There is no force acting upwards

hmm... as said by [Dirocology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/63097/diracology) the bucket is forced by the contact force from the liquid; the normal force is *reactive* to that force.

Normal force plays the role of centripetal force when the velocity of the liquid is greater than $\sqrt{rg}\;.$

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to give a different angle to thinking about this.

Since you mentioned you wanted to consider this from the inertial frame (non rotating), then there is indeed no (fictitious) force. But in that frame, we can consider the water is indeed falling; however, the rate at which the bucket is also "falling" is such that the two stay together - in other words at sufficient speed of rotation the bucket follows the water and the water stays in the bucket.

It is sufficient to demonstrate that the vertical acceleration of the bucket is $\ge g$; for this you can consider the curvature and resulting change in velocity vector. Which looks a lot like the derivation of centripetal force, of course...